# Recursive tricks with regexp in Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I tried to use `regexprep` to solve a problem - I'm given a string, that represents a function; it contains a patterns like these: `'sin(arcsin(f))'` where `f` - any substring; and I need to replace it with simple `'f_2'`.  I successfully used `regexprep` unless I face with such string:

```
str = 'sin(arcsin(sin(arcsin(f_2))))*x^2';
str = regexprep(str, 'sin\(arcsin\((\w*)\)\)','$1');
```

it returns

```
str =

sin(arcsin(f_2))*x^2
```

But I want it to be

```
str =

f_2*x^2
```

Is there any way to solve it (except obvious solution with for-loops).

Comment: Why would you be opposed to using a loop structure?  Using something like a while loop would make your code *intentions* much clearer.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the input is `sin(arcsin(foo(sin(arcsin(bar)))))`? I think once we know that, the answer will become clearer.

Comment: @GigaWatt, I don't refuse to use loop. I'm interested if it's possible to solve a problem without a loop.

Comment: @Floris, the answer is foo(bar). What are the other possible variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to test this, but I thinkg I found an expression that you can call multiple times to do what you asked for; each time it will "strip" one `sin(arcsin())` pair out of your equation. Once it stops changing, you're done.

```
(.*)sin\(arcsin\((.*(\(.*?\))*)(\)\).*$)
```

Here is some Matlab code that shows how this might work:

```
str = 'sin(arcsin(sin(arcsin(f_2))))*x^2';
regex = (.*)sin\(arcsin\((.*(\(.*?\))*)(\)\).*$);

oldlength = 0
newlength = length(str)

while (newlength != oldlength)
  oldlength = newlength;
  str = regexprep(str, regex,'$1$2');
  newlength = length(str);
end
```

As I said - I could not test this. Let me know if you have any problems with this.

Demo of the regular expression:

http://regex101.com/r/bR9gC7

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I noticed in the last sentence, that I've already know the solution with while-loop

Comment: @restrest - your expression did not work with the likes of `sin(arcsin(foo(sin(arcsin(bar)))))` or even just `sin(arcsin(foo(bar)))`... thus I thought you needed a better expression. I realize you knew that a `while` loop could help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern to search for 1 or more (`+`) nested `sin(arcsin(` occurrences:

```
str = 'sin(arcsin(sin(arcsin(f_2))))*x^2';
str2 = regexprep(str, '(sin\(arcsin\()+(\w*)(\)\))+','$2')

str2 =
f_2*x^2
```

Comment: You assume the parenthesis always match the sin/arcsin which may not be true.  For example: `foo(bar(sin(arcsin(x))))` gets reduced to `foo(bar(x` which is no longer valid.

Comment: @GigaWatt Good point. Any want to make the number of occurrences for token 1 match the number of token 3?

Comment: None that I know of.  I'm still thinking that the best approach is a single search-replace inside of a while loop.  If the string is the same after the replacement, then processing is complete.
If you used recursive regular expressions, it would look something like this: `sin\(arcsin\((?:(\w*)|(?R))\)\)`  (untested, I'm not sure Matlab even supports recursive regex)